# Most efficient way to bind several csv of 4 million rows each up to 80 million rows?

Tags: python, r, bash, terminal

I have several files containing ~4 million rows each with the same 4 columns IDs. I am looking for the most efficient way to bind all of them (total rows would be around 80 million). I think it would be equivalent to concatenating all these rows. In R I would simply use

```
rbind(csv1, csv2)
```

but I've tried and it took really long. I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do this, even considering other tools. I am running them in my laptop (8GB RAM).

The number of rows on each file is different ranging from 4 to 2 million each. A sample file would look like this:

```
id chr pos genotype    
rs7349153   1   565490  TC
rs568632519 1   565596  GA
rs534091456 1   565619  AT
rs539860681 1   565643  TC
rs572552962 1   565658  TC
rs375428604 1   565696  CA
```

where **id chr pos genotype**  are the column names. All rows are different, the only pattern is that each file is splitted by chr column (so there is one file with chr1, other with chr2, etc). Final output I expect is a txt with all those rows concatenated, such as:

```
id chr pos genotype    
    rs4349153   1   565490  TC
    rs468622519 1   565396  GA
    rs534091456 2   565319  TT
    rs639810381 2   565443  TT
    rs572552362 3   564658  AC
    rs675422304 3   565396  CA
```

I am open to using any other tools. I've never used a database but I can give it a try.

I also thought about using bash's `cat` but I don't know if I'll have the same problems as with `rbind`

Thank you for your insights!

EDIT: Added more details.

Comment: the question has been tagged with `bash` so I'm assuming you're open to suggestions that don't use `r` so .... I'm not familiar with `rbind()` ... could you provide a bit more detail, perhaps a couple sample lines from each input file and the expected result; also, are the files pre-sorted so that the same set of IDs has the same line number in all files?

Comment: For a `R` way, take a look at the `vroom` package: https://vroom.r-lib.org/#reading-multiple-files

Comment: Is using a database an option in your scenario?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: Added clarification in the post. Files are not pre-sorted, given that each will contain a unique id. I'll check your suggested options. I think my main problem is that when I read and load those gigantic files it requires a lot of memory my computer can't handle, but I don't know if this is an R's issue, so I can try other suggestions.

Comment: How do you work with the data? An SQL database would be helpful if you, for example, select only certain id's, or chr's, etc... as you can put an index on them and then, after an initial lengthy period of loading all of your data into the database (any program will take a long time to load large files), accessing subsets would be quick. If you do not access the data in this way, it might make sense to process it in chunks anyways (and in that case, merging the files might not be necessary). Do you really just need the data in a text file or do you have some goal for it as well?

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion but I won't be accessing it anymore. The processing has been done in each individual file in R, and now client wants it delivered as a single file. I tried concatenating them (aka rbind) by row in R but it took ages, perhaps this is normal for any language? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I've never worked with such huge data frames.

Comment: what format does the final file need to be in?  If it is just a plain text file. You can try a simple `cat` shell command `cat  file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv > concatenated.csv`  After that maybe filter out the header lines with `grep -v '^id'` ...  The problem with calling `rbind` multiple times is that you are pretty much rescanning the whole accumulated DF every time and hence the resulting time complexity is quadratic in the number of files and (linear in the total number of rows), not linear in both as it should be.

Comment: In one comparison, `dplyr::bind_rows` is 5x faster and `data.table::rbindlist` is 10x faster: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/406521_7fc7b6c1dc374e9b8860e15a699d8bb0.html

Comment: I ended up using vroom as suggested above by @markus!! (not sure how to add that as the answer here) Thanks a lot everyone for your comments, I've learnt a lot in the way.